# div display as square and then becomes circle when loading page on iPad

Tags: html, css

When I load the page on iPad it first shows ".dial" in square then after loading the page it becomes circle.

I have already use border-radius 50%. So I want to do like when I load this page ".dial" should be circle from beginning not square at all. This only happens in iPad browser.

Here's my [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/LeoZoe/w4bjc0vg/1/)

and

**Snippet:**

```css
.container {
  width: 600px;
  height: 600px;
  margin: 0 auto;
  background-color: black;
}

.dial {
  position: relative;
  width: 300px;
  height: 300px;
  border-radius: 50%;
  left: 25%;
  top: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
  border: 5px solid @white;
  overflow: hidden;
  background: white;
  transition: width ease-out 0.4s, left ease-out 0.4s;
}

.score-wrapper {
  position: absolute;
  font-size: 5em;
  top: 100px;
  z-index: 1;
  color: white;
}

.gradient {
  background: #ff3232;
  /* Old browsers */
  background: linear-gradient(to right, #ff3232 0%, #f97d2f 30%, #c9c90a 70%, #23e030 100%);
}

.dial-gradient {
  position: absolute;
  //overflow: hidden;
  width: 3000px;
  height: 500px;
  padding-left: 150px;
  li {
    position: relative;
    display: inline-block;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: 4px;
    height: 40px;
    background: rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.2);
    margin-top: 110px;
    margin-bottom: 20px;
    margin-right: 3px;
    bottom: 0;
    z-index: 1;
  }
  .big {
    height: 80px;
    width: 4px;
  }
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="dial">
    <span class="score-wrapper" style="transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, 65, 0);">80%</span>
    <div class="dial-gradient gradient" style="width: 3300px; transform: matrix(1, 0, 0, 1, -2400, 0);">
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
      <li class="big" style="margin-right: 26px;"></li>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: Try this `{border-radius:100vw}`

Comment: Looks like nothing seem to work there is might be problem with transition   property.

Comment: At a guess, it may have been the txtspk "plz" or the "plz help me", which sounds to readers like pleading. Keep your questions short and to the point, and you'll find they are received better over the long term. Ah, and this is your second question where you have deliberately worked around the editor restrictions to add a JS Fiddle link without also showing the code in the question - that definitely deserves a downvote!

Comment: I am not daily user of stackoverflow so don't know this all. I will make sure to keep in my mind. Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

Some browsers do not read percentage in border-radius, because your dial is a fixed height and width adding 300px to border-radius instead of 50% will correct it across all browsers.

```
.dial {
        position: relative;
        width: 300px;
        height: 300px;
        border-radius:300px;
        left: 25%;
        top: calc((100% - 500px) / 2);
        border: 5px solid @white;
        overflow: hidden;
        background: white;
        transition: width ease-out 0.4s, left ease-out 0.4s;
    }
```